# Trouble differentiating expression

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have been asked to differentiate the following expression:

$$f(y)=\left(\frac{e^y}{2}\right)^4$$

the answer according to the worksheet is $\frac{e^{4y}}{y}$

however I cannot get to this point,

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - Can someone also state whether the answer I have been given in the worksheet is correct?

Comment: Apply chain rule. $\frac{1}{16}*4*(e^y)^3*e^y$

Comment: Okay, and what's your question?

Comment: The worksheet does not seem correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{df}{dy} = {1\over 16} e^{4y} \frac{d}{dy} (4y) = \frac{e^{4y}}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$f(y)=(\frac{1}{2}*e^y)^4=\frac{1}{16}e^{4y}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: We can write $$f (y)=\frac {1}{16}e^{4y} $$ We now that $$\frac {d}{dx}(e^{ax}) =ae^{ax} $$ Use that fact to get $f'(y) $. Hope it helps.